# Sliding div in and out on click, but the original isn't showing on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not sure what i've done here, but i'm trying to move my leftside navigation on and of screen. As you can see on the page load(link below), the navigation doesn't show, but once you click on the menu icons things start to move around. Though that isn't working correctly till you click both of the icons once.

Javascript

```
var boxes = $('ul.topLevelNavigation');
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.button').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var box = $($(this).attr('href'));
        if (!box.hasClass("topLevelNavigation")) {
            var current = $('ul.topLevelNavigation');
            current.stop().animate({
                left: '-25%',
            }, 500).removeClass('topLevelNavigation');
            box.stop().animate({
                left: '25%',
            }, 500).addClass('topLevelNavigation');
        }
    });
});
```

link to site http://keithfrenchdesigns.com/RunwayMag/index.html

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Are these your questions 1) why is the navigation hidden on page load and 2) why does the user has to click on both buttons / icons to show the navigation 3) What do I have to do to show the navigation on page load and what to show navigation with a single click?

Comment: Yes. I need the navigation to show on load. Then when the icon on the bottom is clicked it pulls the original off and the new on, then when the top icon is clicked they switch again.

Answer (score 0):

Your navigation doesn't show on page load because you're relying on JavaScript to hide and show it, but your JavaScript only fires when the navigation button is clicked, not on page load. You can do one of two things to fix this.

- **Have JavaScript hide the navigation on page load** - Set `left: -25%` on either `topLevelNavigation1` or `topLevelNavigation2` depending on which one you want to show on page load.
- **Hide your navigation by default with CSS** - Add `left: -25%` by default on your HTML by means of a class (make sure you remember to remove the class with JavaScript when you want to show it) or just add an inline style `<ul class="topLevelNavigation2" style="left: -25%">`.

The second method is definitely the more preferred method as you're not relying on JavaScript to load the initial state of your site and you don't have to wait until the DOM is ready to hide your navigation (potentially having the navigation show and then disappear for no reason).

Regardless of the method you use you'll also need to add the `topLevelNavigation` class to the navigation that's showing be default.

**EDIT**: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/aA5JK/) a jsfiddle demonstrating what I mean.

Comment: Could i possibly get a quick example in a jsfiddle on this?

Comment: Ok, i adjusted the CSS but i'm still not getting the Original navigation set on load. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused on what the desired effect is. Do you want to toggle between two different navigations or do you want toggle 1 navigation? Do you have an example of what you're going for?

Comment: I'm trying to toggle between two. Like seen here http://www.vogue.co.uk/news/2014/1/29/meet-miss-jones when you click the article and menu icons on the left.

Comment: Okay, so assuming you want `<ul class="topLevelNavigation3">` to show by default you would change it like so: `<ul class="topLevelNavigation3 topLevelNavigation" style="left: 25%;">` and the other navigation would be: `<ul class="topLevelNavigation2" style="left: -25%">`.